# Databricks update table not working with orc format

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

Databricks update table not working with orc format.
I created a table with ORC format in hive metastore and it worked fine.
Later I ran UPDATE TABLE and that command failed.
Is there a way to achieve UPDATE using Databricks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databricks delta supports updates, upserts (merge into) and deletes with transactional support. Tables are stored with 'USING DELTA' option, e. g.:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  edate DATE,
  eventId STRING,
  eventType STRING,
  data DECIMAL)
 USING DELTA
 PARTITIONED BY (date)
LOCATION 'wasbs://adls2@sample.blob.core.windows.net/managedtables/events';
```

Data is stored in parquet files with additional transaction logs. See [Databrick Delta Guide](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/delta/index.html) for more details.

ORC is not supported for transactions in Spark. So if you want to update data stored with ORC option, updates can be done by creating a new rowset that is not including the rows to be updated and then creating a second rowset that includes only the updated rows with the new values and then union the two rowsets together.